# ¿Por qué al darle al permiso de ubicación en "Solo esta vez" ya no me vuelve a pedir el permiso? Java/Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy trabajando con una app que solicita permiso de ubicación para poder trabajar, el solicitarlos y obtenerlos ya lo hago, solo que tengo un tema que cuando me muestra el diálogo para marcar la forma en la que quiero otorgar el permiso (Mientras la app está en uso, Sólo esta vez, No permitir) y selecciono "Solo esta vez", al cerrar la app ya no me sale de nuevo el diálogo para saber si otorgar el permiso o no, y se comporta como si le hubiera otorgado el permiso siempre (lo que hace la opción "Mientras la app está en uso"). ¿Cómo puedo lograr que al seleccionar "Solo esta vez" me vuelva a aparecer el diálogo cada que inicio la app y que sirva para todas las versiones de Android?

Este es mi código donde solicito y gestiono el permiso:

```
public class RequestGeolocationActivity extends BaseActivity {

private Button btnContinue;
private Button btnCancel;
private String origin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_geolocation);

    setupUI();
    initListeners();
    getExtras();
}

private void setupUI() {
    btnContinue = findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
    btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
}

private void initListeners() {
    btnContinue.setOnClickListener(continueListener);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(cancelListener);
}

private void getExtras() {
    origin = getIntent().getStringExtra("origin");
}

private final View.OnClickListener continueListener = view -> requestPermission();

private final View.OnClickListener cancelListener = view -> goToActivity(OnboardingChooseAction.class);

private void requestPermission() {
    if (hasGeolocationPermission() && origin.equals("enroll")) {
        goToActivity(RegisterPhoneController.class);
    }
    else if (hasGeolocationPermission() && origin.equals("n2")) {
        goToActivity(RegisterPhoneN2Activity.class);
    }
    else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RequestGeolocationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 0);
        }
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (origin.equals("enroll"))
            goToActivity(RegisterPhoneController.class);
        else
            goToActivity(RegisterPhoneN2Activity.class);
    } else {
        showBottomSheet();
    }
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void showBottomSheet() {
    Dialog bottomSheet = new Dialog(this);
    bottomSheet.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    bottomSheet.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet_request_geolocation);

    Button btnTryAgain = bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.btn_try_again);
    btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        if (!this.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RequestGeolocationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            goToLocationSettings();
        } else {
            requestPermission();
        }
        if (bottomSheet.isShowing()) bottomSheet.dismiss();
    });

    ImageView ivClose = bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.iv_close);
    ivClose.setOnClickListener(v -> bottomSheet.dismiss());

    bottomSheet.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    bottomSheet.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    bottomSheet.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.BottomSheetAnimation;
    bottomSheet.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

    bottomSheet.show();
}

private boolean hasGeolocationPermission() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RequestGeolocationActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

private void goToLocationSettings() {
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
    finish();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}
```

}